# How To get Embed Code Programmatically for a SharePoint Stream Video

Tags: sharepoint-online, angular13

We are having one angular application in which we want to stream a Video uploaded on SharePoint Stream

Using Below option we can get the embeddable url which we can use in

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

tag

[image]

We want to get the src attribute programmatically from SharePoint directly in Angular app without entire embed code. So that we can stream that video in Angular web app.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the solution posted below?

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the iframe to view a video hosted in SharePoint Stream is:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_layouts/15/embed.aspx?UniqueId=32977b69-0556-4990-a089-ee2e96dc88c9
```

Where `UniqueId` is the unique identifier of the list `item.File`

**How to get this value?**

You can use SharePoint REST API to get list items (all items or a specific item with a filter)

Example:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('videos')/items?$select=Id,FileRef,File/UniqueId&$expand=File
```

In the response, you will get the UniqueId!

You can try right now with your web browser.

So you can build the URL to view the video.

[image: video URL]

You can also add a filter to the query to get only one video:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('videos')/items?$select=Id,FileRef,File/UniqueId&$expand=File$filter=FileRef%20eq%20%27/sites/your-site/Videos/your-video.mp4%27
```

To call REST API from Angular app, you need to manage the permission.
Your query must include the following headers:

```
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR-TOKEN",
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
```

Where `YOUR-TOKEN` is generated by an Azure app registration with application permissions for `SharePoint > Sites.Read.All`. There is a lot of articles about generating a token with MSAL to call Microsofy/SharePoint API. For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

[image: Azure app registration]